# How to import R code in Knime

Tags: r, knime

I want to import an R code which is basically the new articles from a website and saving the result in a dataframe.

[image: code screenshot]

Now i want to import that dataframe directly into KNIME with the help of R nodes.

Comment: Have you tried anything in KNIME? What happened?

Comment: hi, i tried with the different nodes in R, but as per my search these can be used to import a R dataframe to knime and not the complete script of R in knime and make it executable from knime.

Answer (score 3):

Place your R code in an [R Source (Table)](https://nodepit.com/node/org.knime.r.RReaderTableNodeFactory) node, from the built-in Scripting > R nodes.

Assign the result you want to a dataframe named `knime.out` and it will be available at the output port of this node as a KNIME table.

Comment: Greetings, Thanks for  your reply...... I found that the R path to home was not set and which was due to Extension called 'Knime Interactive R Statics Integration' . After installing this extension abd multiple reboots, the knime itself picked up the path and now the nodes are working..   But now i have another issue which am posting below.......